# How to model a quasi-exponential function?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, graphing-functions, mathematical-modeling

This is the graphic of official daily deaths caused by Covid-19 in Brazil.

[image: graf1]

And this is the same graphic with an exponential model in red. We see the model don't fit the data.

[image: graf2]

The misadjustment is clearer with a logarithmic Y axis.

[image: graf3]

Looks like the model that would fit here is closer to a "tilted parabola", like the one I drew in blue with Gimp.

[image: graf4]

So my question is: what is the equation of a "tilted parabola" in a graph with logarithmic Y axis? Or: how do I model the present data?

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for functions with **[sub-exponential growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Sub-exponential_time)**. From my limited research, this seems to be a topic more commonly studied in algorithm analysis.

### Definition

[This other answer in stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/64875/809447), provides an intuitive definition of a sub-exponential function $f(x)$:

1. It grows faster than any polynomial

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^a} = \infty\ \forall a$$

2. and it grows more slowly than any exponential

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\ln f(x)}{x} = 0$$

### Example

The function $f(x) = e^{x^\beta}$, with $0 < \beta < 1$ satisfies both conditions:

1.

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{e^{x^\beta}}{x^a} = \infty $$

which clearly goes off to infinity.

2.

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\ln{e^{x^\beta}}}{x} 
 = \lim_{x\to \infty} x^{b - 1} = 0$$

which equals zero, since $b - 1 < 0$

## Caveat with respect to COVID-19 (and epidemiology)

It is possible that your example is better approximated by a *polynomial growth rate!* At least during the first weeks since the outbreak.
[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.07572.pdf) suggests that containment policies in China have managed to suppress the infection growth to the point it followed a rate of $t^\mu$ (where $t$ is time).

Take a look at *page 2* of that paper. When plotted with a *[log-log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log%E2%80%93log_plot)* scale (**NOT** just a single log!), the confirmed cases form a straight line - thus, a polynomial function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the generalized growth model (GGM) is what you're looking for.
$$x' = rx^p,$$
where the sub-exponential part happens when $0<p<1$. Sub-exponential growth is actually way more common than exponential growth, especially on a small scale like a district or city. Here is a [reference](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0025556418300853?casa_token=cwRJaFVPQWYAAAAA:_1P-K-wdbRAZE-F2eASAWY0PKFAHNB2qbCTiCSps5z05TG2MolXZzPgInz1-6oFZSKowBMlLPts).