# means of subexponential growth

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, numerical-methods

I work on an article and there is an ambiguous word for me
It is $\underline{subexponential \ growth}$. I only found its meaning in Wikipedia in group theory, but I want its meaning in complex analysis.
who can describe it and introduce a refrence
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Extracted from page 4 of [this paper](https://idus.us.es/bitstream/handle/11441/87479/1/On%20universal%20entire%20functions%20with%20zero-free%20derivatives.pdf), which is a preprint version of

L. Bernal-González, On universal entire functions with zero-free derivatives, Archiv der Mathematik, vol.17, issue.2, pp.145-150, 1997.

---

An entire function $\Phi:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ is of subexponential type if given $\varepsilon>0$ there is a constant $A$ (depending, possibly, on $\epsilon$) such that $|\Phi(z)|\le A e^{\varepsilon |z|}$.

Analogously, if $\Phi(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$, then $\Phi(z)$ is of subexponetial type if and only if $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(n! |a_n|)^{1/n}=0.$$

Comment: Thanks, but I know it. I want the mean of subexponential growth.

Comment: HAve you seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64862/subexponential-growing-functions)?

Comment: yes, but I need a refrence because it's a problem in my thesis